# uploading a file with Struts2 (the web server which I use is Tomcat 7)

Tags: file-upload, struts2

When I used Struts2 to upload a file ,I clicked submit in jsp, however, tomcat showed me the wrong message,I have searched on the Internet, but I can't find the answer,so I hope someone can help me ,thanks!

**The Wrong Message is below:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - 
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
lanxiaoxing.upload.upLoadAction.execute(upLoadAction.java:58)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

**the struts.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="lanxiaoxing.user" extends="struts-default">
<action name="loginUser" class="lanxiaoxing.user.userAction">
  <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
  <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
<package name="lanxiaoxing.upload" extends="struts-default">
<action name="upLoad" class="lanxiaoxing.upload.upLoadAction">
  <result name="SUCCESS">upload_success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**the upLoadAction.java is:**

```
package lanxiaoxing.upload;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.struts2.*;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.*;

public class upLoadAction extends ActionSupport{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private File lanxiaoxingfile;
private String lanxiaoxingfileContentType;
private String lanxiaoxingfileName;
private String savePath;


private String getSavePath(){
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    return request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(savePath);
}


public File getlanxiaoxingfile(){
    return lanxiaoxingfile;
}
public void setlanxiaoxingfile(File lanxiaoxingfile){
    this.lanxiaoxingfile=lanxiaoxingfile;
}

public String getlanxiaoxingfileContentType(){
    return lanxiaoxingfileContentType;
}
public void setlanxiaoxingfileContenType(String lanxiaoxingfileContentType){
    this.lanxiaoxingfileContentType=lanxiaoxingfileContentType;
}

public String getlanxiaoxingfileName(){
    return lanxiaoxingfileName;
}
public void setlanxiaoxingfileName(String lanxiaoxingfileName){
    this.lanxiaoxingfileName=lanxiaoxingfileName;
}

public void setsavePath(String savePath){
    this.savePath=savePath;
}

public String execute() throws Exception{
    setsavePath("");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getSavePath()+"\\"+getlanxiaoxingfileName());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getlanxiaoxingfile());

    byte[]buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len=0;
    while((len=fis.read(buffer))>0){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like it could not find the file. Can I see your action mapping on struts.xml and JAVA part?

Comment: would like to see this part `lanxiaoxing.upload.upLoadAction.execute(upLoadAction.java:58)`

Answer (score 1):

Your getter and setter names are all incorrect; they should follow normal Java naming conventions, and the conventions expected by the file upload interceptor, e.g.:

```
public void setLanxiaoxingfile(File lanxiaoxingfile) { // Note capital "L"
```

This assumes a file input field with the name "lanxiaoxinfile".

*IMO the `"file"` portion of that variable name is redundant.*

See the [file upload docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html) for more info.

Also, as tusar says, the result name should be lower-case `"success"`, or just left blank, as that is the default. The default stack already contains the `"fileUpload"` interceptor, though, so re-configuring it for this action would be redundant and misleading.

Consider doing the file copy via a utility method, or just use one of the [Commons IO file copy utilities](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29).

Comment: +1 for nice review ! and I had reverted that previous answer for future visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload using Struts2 and missing the `fileUpload` and `defaultStack` interceptors seems causing the error. Try changing your action-declaration like :

```
<action name="upLoad" class="lanxiaoxing.upload.upLoadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">999999999999</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">upload_success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Also , `SUCCESS` is actually a String `"success"` thats why I modified the result-name to small letters.
While learning, it is always good to follow a [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/12/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example.html).